# Easy IIS install of php

Tags: php, iis

Are there any "all-in-one" installers for php + mysql on iis? Preferably with a gui configuration interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP part is easy with Web Platform Installer:

http://php.iis.net/

MySQL is a breeze to install on Windows:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#win32

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any all-in-one installers for both MySql and PHP, but PHP itself comes with an automated installer that will attach itself to IIS - but the preferred method is still manual (the automated procedure only uses CGI). There are plenty of how-to pages on the web that give you the step-by-step procedure required to get setup (and these differ based on your version of IIS) - I suggest you use one of those instead.

Some links to get you started:
[PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis.php)
[Installing PHP 5 on IIS in 5 simple steps](http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/installing_php_5_on_iis_in_5_simple_steps)

Comment: It is actually more for running open source bug tracking apps, project management apps, etc and not for doing any dev so speed isn't that important.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a direct answer, but a ***point of interest only***. If you are looking for something that runs php/mysql that is quick to get setup for testing purposes you could try using a [virtual appliance](http://virtualappliances.net/products/lamp.php)+[vmware server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/)/[player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/)

Comment: I've tried running virtual machines but the server doesn't like the extra load.

Comment: Really? Hrm, thats inetrsting. I have found that the specialized virtual machines can run on tiny amounts of ram (depends of course on what you are doing) and the server desnt even break a sweat. Oh well. Anyhow, sorry i could not have been more help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any all in one installers, but you are probably better off just installing MySQL and PHP seperately. It's pretty straight forward.

MySQL has a GUI installation wizard in windows. I'm assume you know where to download this. You can download PHP for IIS from the Microsoft website here. It will have a GUI interface to some extent for installation:
http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=PHP53

You will probably need to still reference MySQL by editing the php.ini file manually. This is a particually good FAQ:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/353/install-and-configure-mysql-for-php-applications-on-iis-7-and-above/